# Bitrix24 - Webhook how to get data phone in array

Tags: arrays, content-management-system, bitrix

In bitrix24 it is possible to create webhooks to obtain contact data. In contacts, the phone field is an array that is made up of several arrays but I don't understand how I can get the data from the work phone or landline phone array.

To get the phone data I use SELECT[] with the PHONE parameter. Can anyone help me with the structure, I've tried PHONE[0] without success.

Thank you in advance

```
 [PHONE] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => Array
                            (
                                [ID] => 45545
                                [VALUE_TYPE] => WORK
                                [VALUE] => +351911111111
                                [TYPE_ID] => PHONE
                            )

                        [1] => Array
                            (
                                [ID] => 45547
                                [VALUE_TYPE] => MOBILE
                                [VALUE] => +351910000000
                                [TYPE_ID] => PHONE
                            )

                        [2] => Array
                            (
                                [ID] => 45549
                                [VALUE_TYPE] => HOME
                                [VALUE] => +351220000000
                                [TYPE_ID] => PHONE
                            )

                        [3] => Array
                            (
                                [ID] => 45551
                                [VALUE_TYPE] => FAX
                                [VALUE] => +351210000000
                                [TYPE_ID] => PHONE
                            )

                        [4] => Array
                            (
                                [ID] => 45553
                                [VALUE_TYPE] => PAGER
                                [VALUE] => +351230000000
                                [TYPE_ID] => PHONE
                            )

                        [5] => Array
                            (
                                [ID] => 45555
                                [VALUE_TYPE] => MAILING
                                [VALUE] => +351240000000
                                [TYPE_ID] => PHONE
                            )

                        [6] => Array
                            (
                                [ID] => 45557
                                [VALUE_TYPE] => OTHER
                                [VALUE] => +351250000000
                                [TYPE_ID] => PHONE
                            )

                    )
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of getting the field in the webhook, on the javascript side I'll read the field value = work and the problem is solved.